# Basic Menu with Cases

Tags: java, menu, switch-statement, case, user-input

I am creating a basic banking app that tracks a user's bank account activities, and I cannot seem to figure out why when I run my code that it is simply running what I have set for the "default" case; so even when I press 1,2,3, or 4, the console states, "Error -- Please choose a valid option."

Thanks in advance!

```
package Account;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Account extends Bank {
 int Balance;
 int Previoustransaction;
 int amount;
 int amount2;
 String Name;
 String ID;

 Account(String Name,String ID){
    
 }
 void deposit(int amount) {
    if (amount != 0) {
        Balance+=amount;
        Previoustransaction=amount;
     }
   }
   void withdraw(int amount) {
     if(amount!=0) {
        Balance-=amount;
        Previoustransaction = -amount;
     } 
        }
   void getPrevioustransaction() {
      if(Previoustransaction > 0) {
        System.out.println("Deposited:" + Previoustransaction);
     }
     else if(Previoustransaction<0) {
        System.out.println("Withdrawn:" + Math.abs(Previoustransaction));
     }  else {
        System.out.println("No transaction occurred.");     
     }
    }
      void Menu() {
        int choice = 0;
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Welcome," + Name + ".");
     System.out.println("Your account number is" + ID);
     System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
     System.out.println("1.Check balance.");
     System.out.println("2. Make a deposit.");
     System.out.println("3. Make a withrawl.");
     System.out.println("4. Show last transaction.");
     System.out.println("0. Exit.");
    
     do {
         System.out.println("Choose an option.");
         choice = scan.nextInt();
         System.out.println();
        
         switch(choice) {
        
         case'1':
            
            System.out.println("Balance = $" + Balance);
            System.out.println();
            break;
            
         case'2':
            System.out.println("Enter an amount to deposit.");
            int amount = scan.nextInt();
            deposit (amount);
            System.out.println();
            break;
            
        case'3':
            System.out.println("Enter an amount to withdrawl.");
            int amount2 = scan.nextInt();
            withdraw(amount2);
            break;
            
        case '4':
            getPrevioustransaction();
            break;
            
        case '0':
            break;
            
        default:
        System.out.println("Error -- Please choose a valid option.");
        }
      } while (choice != 0);
        System.out.println("Thank you for using the Bank Account Tracker!");
        
        scan.close();
      }
      {
        
            
            
      }     
      {
                
      } 
    

      }
```

Comment: You have a problem with your var types. choice is an integer but you compare it to chars in the switch case. change '1' to 1 '2' to 2 after every case. You got it?

Comment: So you’re saying rename my cases then? (Case 1 to 2, case 2 to 3, etc)

Comment: You have something like case ‚1‘: change it to case 1: use numbers after case not string/char

Comment: Okay, I understand now! Now, when I select 2 to deposit and type a number to deposit, it states "Choose an option" instead of Deposited: $500". What would this be from?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me!

Comment: Well you have a loop that says unless someone types a 0 ask them for their option. As you type 2, its not 0 so it will repeat. You forgot to call the getPrevioustransaction() method in your loop. I think you want it right before System.out.println("Choose an option."); and after do{. One last note to naming conventions. You have a method called Menu. Methods should be lowerCamelCase so it should start with a lowercase letter. Same rule applies to variable names. Balance should be balance. Previoustransaction should be previousTransaction.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your program isn't working as you expect is that:

- you are prompting for user input
- capturing that input as a numeric value; specifically, primitive data type `int`
- comparing that `int` input against various *character* values – that is, values of primitive data type `ch` (such as `'1'`)

Here's a paired down version of what you're doing:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int choice = scanner.nextInt();
switch (choice) {
    case '1':
        System.out.println("match");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("some other input found: " + choice);
}
```

Here's that same block, but instead of `case '1'` (which matches on a single character value), I changed it to `case 1` (which matches on an integer value):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int choice = scanner.nextInt();
switch (choice) {
    case 1: // <-- this is the only edit, use 1 instead of '1'
        System.out.println("match");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("some other input found: " + choice);
}
```

So, to fix your program, change your various `case` statements to use integer values, not characters.